# Android method rewrite to Lambda

Tags: android

I've want to rewrite the method to Lamda.

```
CheckCar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckMotor.setChecked(false);
        et_mileage.setText(String.valueOf(DistanceTextD_Car));
    }
});enter code here
```

Lamda：
CheckCar.setOnClickListener(view->CheckMotor.setChecked(false));

But how to add et_mileage.setText(String.valueOf(DistanceTextD_Car));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the single expression to a statement block

```
CheckCar.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    CheckMotor.setChecked(false));
    et_mileage.setText(String.valueOf(DistanceTextD_Car));
});
```

As [the docs say](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), the arrow token `->` is followed by

> A body, which consists of a single expression **or a statement block.**

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckCar.setOnClickListener(view-> {
    CheckMotor.setChecked(false);
    et_mileage.setText(String.valueOf(DistanceTextD_Car));
});
```